# Update function parameters onblur of textarea

Tags: javascript, html

So I am working on this for hours and hours and I am not able to find the correct algorithm of how can I update the parameters of a function when the value of a textarea changes.

```js
<script>
    details = "";
    postid = <? php echo $_GET['id']; ?> ;
    userid = <? php echo User::GetUserID($_SESSION['username']); ?> ;
    postedby = posted_by;

    function offerIt() {
        //created a function so that we can get the latest value of the textarea because at first it was giving the default value which was null because at the page load the value is null of the textarea
        addPostOffer('' + details + ',' + postid + ',' + userid + ',' + postedby + '');
    }
</script>
<textarea placeholder="Type in you offer details" rows="5" class="input-block-level" id="offer_details" onblur="details=this.value"></textarea>
<script>
    document.write("<input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary pull-right' onclick='offerIt()' value='Offer It' />");
</script>
```

So actually I want the `details` variable to get updated. First I set its value to "" then `onblur` of the value of the textarea(`#offer_details`) but now after that I want the parameter of addPostOffer to be updated aswell but that's not happening! How can I do that?

And here's what the `document.write` is writing:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="offerIt()" value="Offer It">
```

Please help.

Comment: Hey, just curious, was this resolved with help from the answers below?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code, the problem is here:

```
postid = <? php echo $_GET['id']; ?> ;
userid = <? php echo User::GetUserID($_SESSION['username']); ?> ;
```

That shall be changed to:

```
postid = "<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>";
userid = "<?php echo User::GetUserID($_SESSION['username']); ?>";
```

The whole code now becomes, I added posted_by = userid; to define it:

```
<script>
    details = "";
    postid = "<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>";
    userid = "<?php echo User::GetUserID($_SESSION['username']); ?>";
  posted_by = userid;
    postedby = posted_by;

    function offerIt() {
        //created a function so that we can get the latest value of the textarea because at first it was giving the default value which was null because at the page load the value is null of the textarea
        addPostOffer('' + details + ',' + postid + ',' + userid + ',' + postedby + '');
    }
</script>
<textarea placeholder="Type in you offer details" rows="5" class="input-block-level" id="offer_details" onblur="details=this.value"></textarea>
<script>
    document.write("<input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary pull-right' onclick='offerIt()' value='Offer It' />");
</script>
```